# Extend BERT or any transformer model using manual features

Tags: huggingface-transformers, text-classification, bert-language-model

I have been doing a thesis in my citation classifications. I just implemented Bert model for the classification of citations. I have 4 output classes and I give an input sentence and my model returns an output that tells the category of citation. Now my supervisor gave me another task.

You have to search that whether it is possible to extend BERT or any transformer model using manual features. e.g. You are currently giving a sentence as the only input followed by its class. What if you can give a sentence, and some other features as input; as we do in other classifiers?

I need some guidance about this problem. How can I add an extra feature in my Bert model and the feature would be categorical not numerical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The are several ways to achieve that. I will explain just two in the following answer:

1. Add category as a token:
   The idea of this approach is rather simple when transformer models like BERT are able to produce contextualized embeddings for a given sentence, why can't we incorporate categorical features as text as well? For example, you use the title of a cited paper as input and also want to incorporate the research area of the paper to provide more context:

```
"Attention is all you need. [Computer Science] [Machine Translation]" -> BERT
```

To do that, I would add the categories of your new feature as separate tokens to BERT (that is not required but reduces the sequence length) and fine-tune it for a few epochs:

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForSequenceClassification

my_categories = ["[Computer Science]", "[Machine Translation]"]
sentence="Attention is all you need. [Computer Science] [Machine Translation]"

t= BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
m=BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
# tokenized without separate tokens
print(len(t(sentence)["input_ids"]))

# tokenized without separate tokens
t.add_tokens(my_categories)
print(len(t(sentence)["input_ids"]))

# Extend embedding layer of model
m.resize_token_embeddings(len(t.get_vocab()))

# Training...
```

Output:

```
18
12
Embedding(28998, 768, padding_idx=0)
```

2. Separate Embedding layer:
   A more traditional way is to hold an embedding for each category and concatenate (or any other method to combine features) it with the contextualized output of BERT before you feed it to the classification layer. For this approach, you can simply copy the code from huggingfaces [BertForSequenceClassification](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.21.2/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L1510) class (or whatever class you are using) and make the required changes:

```py
import torch
from torch.nn import BCEWithLogitsLoss, CrossEntropyLoss, MSELoss
from transformers import BertPreTrainedModel, BertModel
from typing import Optional

class MyBertForSequenceClassification(BertPreTrainedModel):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.num_labels = config.num_labels
        self.config = config

        self.bert = BertModel(config)
        classifier_dropout = (
            config.classifier_dropout if config.classifier_dropout is not None else config.hidden_dropout_prob
        )
        self.dropout = torch.nn.Dropout(classifier_dropout)
        
        # Modified +20
        self.classifier = torch.nn.Linear(config.hidden_size +20, config.num_labels)

        # Modified 50 different categories embedding dimension 20 
        self.my_categorical_feature = torch.nn.Embedding(50,20)

        # Initialize weights and apply final processing
        self.post_init()

    # Modified new parameter categorical_feature_ids
    def forward(
        self,
        input_ids: Optional[torch.Tensor] = None,
        attention_mask: Optional[torch.Tensor] = None,
        token_type_ids: Optional[torch.Tensor] = None,
        position_ids: Optional[torch.Tensor] = None,
        head_mask: Optional[torch.Tensor] = None,
        inputs_embeds: Optional[torch.Tensor] = None,
        labels: Optional[torch.Tensor] = None,
        output_attentions: Optional[bool] = None,
        output_hidden_states: Optional[bool] = None,
        return_dict: Optional[bool] = None,
        categorical_feature_ids = None,
    ):

        return_dict = return_dict if return_dict is not None else self.config.use_return_dict

        outputs = self.bert(
            input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            token_type_ids=token_type_ids,
            position_ids=position_ids,
            head_mask=head_mask,
            inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds,
            output_attentions=output_attentions,
            output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
            return_dict=return_dict,
        )

        pooled_output = outputs[1]

        # Modified get embeddings
        my_categorical_embedding = self.my_categorical_feature(categorical_feature_ids)
        my_categorical_embedding = self.dropout(my_categorical_embedding)

        pooled_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)
        
        # Modified concatenate contextualized embeddings from BERT and your categorical embedding
        pooled_output = torch.cat((pooled_output, my_categorical_embedding), dim=-1)

        logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)

        loss = None
        if labels is not None:
            if self.config.problem_type is None:
                if self.num_labels == 1:
                    self.config.problem_type = "regression"
                elif self.num_labels > 1 and (labels.dtype == torch.long or labels.dtype == torch.int):
                    self.config.problem_type = "single_label_classification"
                else:
                    self.config.problem_type = "multi_label_classification"

            if self.config.problem_type == "regression":
                loss_fct = MSELoss()
                if self.num_labels == 1:
                    loss = loss_fct(logits.squeeze(), labels.squeeze())
                else:
                    loss = loss_fct(logits, labels)
            elif self.config.problem_type == "single_label_classification":
                loss_fct = CrossEntropyLoss()
                loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1))
            elif self.config.problem_type == "multi_label_classification":
                loss_fct = BCEWithLogitsLoss()
                loss = loss_fct(logits, labels)
        if not return_dict:
            output = (logits,) + outputs[2:]
            return ((loss,) + output) if loss is not None else output

        return {
            "loss":loss,
            "logits":logits,
            "hidden_states":outputs.hidden_states,
            "attentions":outputs.attentions,
        }
```

You can use this class just as the BertForSerquenceClassification class, the only difference is, that it expects `categorical_feature_ids` as additional input:

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForSequenceClassification

t= BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
m= MyBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")

# batch with two sentences (i.e. the citation text you have already used) 
i = t(["paper title 1", "paper title 2"], padding=True, return_tensors="pt")

# We assume that the first sentence (i.e. paper title 1) belongs to category 23 and the second sentence to category 42
# You probably want to use a dictionary in your own code 
i["categorical_feature_ids"] = torch.tensor([23,42])

print(m(**i))
```

Output:

```
{'loss': None, 
'logits': tensor([[ 0.6069, -0.1878], [ 0.6347, -0.2608]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>), 
'hidden_states': None, 
'attentions': None}
```

Comment: I want you to see my code 
is it possible? can we arrange a call

Comment: I didn't understand here `i = t(["test", "test1234"], padding=True, return_tensors="pt")`. Here **test** and **test1234** are two different categories and we are just using array of categories in place of sentences in tokenise method.
tell me if am wrong or right

Comment: I have edit my question please have a look @cronoik

Comment: You can click on my profile to connect via LinkedIn. Can you please also revert your question and open a separate one? On StackOverflow we try to have a good set of questions and answers and your edits are a bit too much to still address with this answer. I will have a look as soon as you have posted it.

Comment: `["test", "test1234"]` are not categories, they are the sentences you are already using. The categories are in the next line. `test` has category `23` and `test1234` has category `42`. I will add a comment to make it clear.

Comment: I used your approach. I have understood but I still have a small doubt, where we will give our additional feature as an input. For example, you can see that we are giving our input in tokenize method of Bert tokenizer. But what about other features.
It's ok that we can created extra embedding layer for each feature but how will we inject those features (as an input) in our model.
Please have a look at this link https://github.com/Umar888/bert_implementation/blob/main/extra%20embedding%20layer.ipynb
I have updated my code using your approach. Please clear my doubt. Thank you